# OBIEE 11g: How do you navigate to a value of another report in the same analysis?

Tags: oracle11g, obiee

I have one analyse with two tables. The first table is a master and the second table has all childs. Is there an option to make a action link in the first table that redirects to the value of in the second table of that master while it stays in the same analysis? How can this be done? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable master-detail between different views of the same (or different) analysis.

In the first table you need to add an action on the column that you want to become the master column. In criteria tab go to properties of that column, and on the Interaction tab select the "Send Master-Detail events". You can put any arbitrary word there, as long as there are no other channels with the same name.

Then on the second table, you have to edit its properties so it "listens for Master-Detail" events. Just provide the same word for the channel name.

There are some restrictions to this feature... You should read the official documentation to get more details.

(doc [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/bi.1111/e10544/creatingviews.htm#BIEUG2811))